# JavaScript JSON object with square brackets and spaces in name

Tags: javascript, json

I have encountered a JSON Structure I have never seen before.  This is using Square Bracket ([]) but has spaces in the name.  How would I navigate such a structure?

```
"profile": [{
  "[Profile ID]": 1001398965,
  "[Name | Prefix]": "Ms.",
  "[Name | First]": "Lori",
  "[Name | Middle]": "",
  "[Name | Last]": "Smith",
  "[Name | Suffix]": "",
  "[Contact Name]": "Lori Smith"
},
{  "[Profile ID]": 1001398965,
  "[Name | Prefix]": "Ms.",
  "[Name | First]": "Jeanine",
  "[Name | Middle]": "",
  "[Name | Last]": "Samson",
  "[Name | Suffix]": "",
  "[Contact Name]": "Jeanine Samson"
}]
```

I have tried

```
profile[0]['Name | First']  //result undefined

profile[0][Name | First]   //result Name is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: profile[0][Name | First]: your program is looking for "Name" and "First" variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets are part of the key. You have to use:

```
profile[0]['[Name | First]']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
j['profile'][0]['[Name | Prefix]']
```

See this snippet:

```js
var j = {
  "profile": [{
    "[Profile ID]": 1001398965,
    "[Name | Prefix]": "Ms.",
    "[Name | First]": "Lori",
    "[Name | Middle]": "",
    "[Name | Last]": "Smith",
    "[Name | Suffix]": "",
    "[Contact Name]": "Lori Smith"
  },
  {  "[Profile ID]": 1001398965,
    "[Name | Prefix]": "Ms.",
    "[Name | First]": "Jeanine",
    "[Name | Middle]": "",
    "[Name | Last]": "Samson",
    "[Name | Suffix]": "",
    "[Contact Name]": "Jeanine Samson"
  }]
};

console.log(j['profile'][0]['[Name | Prefix]']);
```